# How to select the cells in a column that have a specific text in their value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the cells that contain match the certain text criteria I search for.

I keep getting the error

> Run-Time error 424 Object required

on line 12

```
cell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_num)
```

and I'm not sure why?

Any and all help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
Option Compare Text

Sub FindingColumn()
Dim Col1Rng As Range, Col3Rng As Range
Dim Column1Search As String, Column2Search As String, Column3Search As 
String
row_num = 0

Column1Search = InputBox("Col 1 Criteria: ")

Do
DoEvents
row_num = row_num + 1
cell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_num)
    If Col2Rng = Empty And InStr(cell, Column1Search) Then
        Col2Rng = cell.Address(0, 0)
    ElseIf InStr(cell, Column1Search) Then
        Col2Rng = Col2Rng & "," & cell.Address(0, 0)

    End If
Loop Until cell = ""

Range(Col2Rng).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: First, add `Option Explicit` and declare all variables - you're missing `row_num`, `cell` and  `Col2Rng`.

Comment: I did that and now I get error " Object variable or With block variable not set" on line 'cell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_num)

Comment: Yes because you need the word `Set` before an object variable: `Set cell = ...`.

Comment: Also why not just filter?

Comment: Ok I understand that. I'm now getting an error to the way I'm attempting to set the range to Col2Rng stating that it is a Type mismatch. I'm not sure how exactly I would go about assigning it correctly

Comment: The task as a whole eliminated the possibility of filtering the way excel does.

Comment: @Pvelez_3 Col2Rng is a range but an address is a string

Answer (score 0):

This should serve as the basis for what you're trying to do

```
Sub FindingColumn()
    Dim Col1Rng As Range, Column1Search As String, foundCellCol1 As Range
    Set Col1Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    Column1Search = InputBox("Col 1 Criteria: ")
    Set foundCellCol1 = Col1Rng.Find(What:=Column1Search)
    If Not foundCellCol1 Is Nothing Then foundCellCol1.Select Else: MsgBox "Search term not found!"
End Sub
```

Can you generate a list in another location of all of the items that match?

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindingColumn()
    Dim Col1Rng As Range, Column1Search As String, foundCellCol1 As Range, lastRow As Long, lastFoundRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Col1Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    Column1Search = InputBox("Col 1 Criteria: ")
    Set foundCellCol1 = Col1Rng.Find(What:="*" & Column1Search & "*")
    While Not foundCellCol1 Is Nothing
        If Not foundCellCol1 Is Nothing Then
            Range("B" & Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = foundCellCol1.Value
            Set Col1Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & foundCellCol1.Row & ":A" & lastRow)
            lastFoundRow = foundCellCol1.Row
            Set foundCellCol1 = Col1Rng.Find(What:="*" & Column1Search & "*")
            If foundCellCol1.Row = lastFoundRow Then Set foundCellCol1 = Nothing
        End If
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: And instead of using Range("A:A"), I would find the last cell with data in the column using whatever technique you prefer...so you don't put the entirety of column A in memory.

Comment: foundCellCol1.Select throws a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error

Comment: I'm not seeing that error. I have "test1" through "test8" in cells A1-A8. If I enter "test4" as the search term, cell A4 gets selected without an error.

Comment: You may have to wrap your code with an If statement for the case when the term you're searching for isn't present in the range.

Comment: Column A looks more like Xy_Db_001 with the "Xy" changing to different strings. I'm looking to select all the rows in the column that contain "Xy" regardless of case sensitivity.

Comment: Again, you'll need to add a condition for when your string isn't found in the first run...that is if foundCellCol1 is Nothing on the first attempt then put a message saying so (or whatever you want to do...Exit Sub, End...whatever you want to do)